# Trying to understand what skipped means in the play recap (Ansible)

Tags: ansible

What does skipped mean in the play recap?
for example below, it shows skipped=17

```
PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=24   changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=17   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Skipped is tightly linked with conditionals. You should read this documentation article: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html

Answer (score 1):

Skipped means a task got skipped.
This happens for example if you run a specific task only (with a when statement) if a variable contains a certain value.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html